# Column space of a matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times q}$, $C\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times q}$ be matrices such that $$C=AB$$ where $C$ and  $B$ are full column rank.

Then do $C$ and $B$ have the same column space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily for example let
$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2\\
3 & 4
\end{bmatrix}
, \quad 
B=
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then
$$
AB=C=
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now both $C$ and $B$ have column rank $1$ (full rank) but column space of $B$ and $C$ are for sure not the same.